# Why map.has() return false for deleted object?

Tags: javascript

```js
let john = { name: "John" };

let map = new Map();
map.set(john, "...");

let weakmap = new WeakMap();
weakmap.set(john, "...");

console.log(map.has(john));       // true
console.log(weakmap.has(john));   // true

john = null; 

console.log(map.has(john));       // false line A
console.log(weakmap.has(john));   // false line B

console.log(map);      // Map { {…} → "..." }  Line C
console.log(weakmap);  // WeakMap { {…} → "..." }  Line D
```

1. I know even if the  garbage collector remove an object, this object will be available in Map. So i expect output 'true' on 'line A' but it print false What am i missing?
2. Why am i seeing john object on line C and line D? If line A and B result false why line C and D are printing john object?

Comment: `map.has(null)` ==> `false`

Comment: By setting `john` to null, you lost a way to check that the *original* key exists in the map.

Comment: NB: the whole idea you seem to have is going to fail anyway, because the regular map still has a reference to the original `john`, which is why it will  *not* be garbage collected and disappear from the weak map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to demonstrate the difference between a regular map and a weak map. But it is not going to work for one simple reason:

You cannot detect whether an object is garbage collected through JavaScript code, as that would necessitate you somehow still have a reference to check with. But if you have a reference, then it is impossible that it would have been garbage collected.

To your questions:

> I know even if the garbage collector remove an object, this object will be available in Map.

This is not true. If you have it in a regular map, then that constitutes a reference to the object, and so it cannot be garbage collected.

> So i expect output 'true' on 'line A' but it print false What am i missing?

There is no way to write JavaScript code that would print `true` for the map and `false` for the weak map. Your test was flawed because you changed `john` to be something else, so your `.has(john)` calls were not about the original object, but about the new value you gave to this variable. So these results are unrelated to the original object you had stored in the maps.

> Why am i seeing john object on line C and line D? If line A and B result false why line C and D are printing john object?

Because the `false` output was not about the original john object, but about `null`.

Also realise that console is doing you a favour in showing you the content of the WeakMap just like that, while in JavaScript code you cannot iterate over all content of a WeakMap.

Answer (score 1):

By typing `john = null` you are replacing the old pointer with a new pointer to `null` and you no can no longer access the previous `john` in order to use it as a key for the `Map`, so what you observe is completely normal. The key of the `Map` is the **value** of `john` (which you have lost on purpose), not the **name** of the variable.

The previous value of `john` is not garbage collected because still referenced from the `Map` and you still can retrieve it with one of these:

- [Map.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map/entries)
- [Map.prototype.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map/keys)
- [Map.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map/@@iterator)
- [Map.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

`john = null;` does not delete the object that was previously referred to by `john`, it sets the *variable* `john` to point at `null` instead of the object it was previously pointed at.

When you run `console.log(map.has(john));`, now that `john` is set to `null`, it's equivalent to you running `console.log(map.has(null));`. The map has no entry keyed by `null` so it returns false.

> I know even if the garbage collector remove an object, this object will be available in Map.

This is incorrect. The garbage collector *will not* remove an object that has any strong reference still pointing to it. Even if you set `john` to `null`, dropping that reference to the object, your Map still has a key pointing to it, so the garbage collector will not free it from memory. If you only had the WeakMap, it might be garbage collected when the garbage collector runs next - but this won't happen quickly enough for you to observe it in the same block of code.